# Contour Integral of a rational function with complex denominator: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ibx}}{x^2+a^2} dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

What is the best approach to evaluate the contour integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ibx}}{x^2+a^2} dx$$

in the case that a is complex, $Re(a) > 0$ and b is positive?

If $a$ was real, I can determine the result by using a semicircular contour,

applying Jordan's Lemma along the arc, and then using the residue theorem to

compute the residue at z= ia.  I assume that I need to a similar thing here, but

I'm having trouble actually determining the residues and when they are inside

the contour.  If I write $a = a_{1}+ia_{2}$  then I have:

$a^{2} = a_{1}^{2}+2ia_{1}a_{2}-a_{2}^{2}$  so I'm looking for the roots of:

$z^{2}+a_{1}^{2}+2ia_{1}a_{2}-a_{2}^{2}= 0$.  Would I proceed by writing

z and a in polar form?  I feel like there is an easier way to do this.  Any

suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Surely the poles are at $\pm ia$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roots of $z^2+a^2$ are $\pm ai$ and$$\operatorname{res}_{z=\pm ai}\frac{e^{ibz}}{z^2+a^2}=\frac{e^{ib\times(\pm ai)}}{\pm2ai}=\pm\frac{e^{\mp ab}}{2ai}=\mp\frac{e^{\mp ab}}{2a}i.$$

Comment: Thank you, I feel very silly for asking this now.